# TextBox events in c# on press enter

Tags: c#, winforms

Which event do I need to use when user write some value in text Box, and after pressing enter to execute something?

I need when user write numbers and when he press enter to calculate something in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `KeyDown` event like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Test"); // Or call a method
    }
}
```

When you set the `AcceptButton` in the form you should also set the `AcceptButton` property to null when enter `TextBox` and reassign the button to it when Leave the `TextBox` like this:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = button1;
}

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AcceptButton = null;
}
```